# Problem in removing white space around image

Tags: html, css

There is a problem in removing the whitespace from the first GIF I posted for my website. I cannot understand why this particular GIF is showing white space while the others are perfectly normal. Please help?

[image]

Comment: can u plz send the code?

Comment: @Manikandan2811                                                                                                             #boxes .box img{

width:90px;

display: block;
}
This defines the style done on the three GIF's uploaded. Could the problem be due to their different size?

Comment: consider adding the related `HTML` and `CSS` parts.

Comment: Seems that the first image isn't transparent? Whitespace isn't the same as transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't code related. The image itself isn't transparent so will need editing.

1. Download Paint.net
   1.1 Download link https://www.dotpdn.com/files/paint.net.4.2.install.zip
   1.2 Manual: https://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/InstallPDN.html
2. **You should make your "smile image"  as transparent** https://superuser.com/questions/508172/changing-transparency-in-paint-net
   use  the answer by Gruber
3. Then add changed image to the HTML. The white square will take the color of your background.

Comment: It seems to work fine now. Thank you very much